# Difference between Firebase service account key files from Firebase and from GCloud?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am running scripts to interact with Firestore (e.g. creating a doc). I've provided a service account key file to do so (tried with key files from Firebase and GCloud) - scripts run the same.

I am aware that Firebase is now built / closely linked to GCloud so I am expecting the key files to be similar.

However, the docs recommend initializing the sdk with a key from Firebase console when [adding Firebase admin to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) and from GCloud Console for [unit testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#online-mode).

So here are my questions:

- Why recommend 2 different ways to generate them? Is one more appropriate than the other?
- Do service account key files generated in Firebase (1) and GCloud (2) consoles differ in terms of scope? Do they allow the same operations? Are they granted equivalent permissions?

---

1. Firebase Console > Project Settings > Service Accounts > Firebase Admin SDK > Create new private key
   https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[my-project-id]/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk
2. Google Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Service Accounts > App Engine default service account > Create key
   https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=[my-project-id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service account and credentials provided by the Firebase console are no different than one that you'd create in the Cloud console.  *Firebase is just making it easier to get started, so you don't have to learn the Cloud console.*  If you want to use the one provided by Firebase, fine.  If you want to use one you create and configure in the Cloud console, fine.  The Firebase service account should be visible in the Cloud console just like any other.  When it comes to assigning permissions to individual products, you can still choose either one to work with.  It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Doug. That's what I initially thought but the docs recommending 2 approaches through me off. I think it would make more sense to recommended retrieving the service account key for unit testing from the Firebase console to keep it consistent.

Comment: Feel free to send feedback about the documentation using the "send feedback" button at the top right of every page of Firebase docs.

Comment: Will do. You said "When it comes to assigning permissions to individual products, you can still choose either one to work with" - what do you mean by that? To the best of my knowledge, the service key grants you permissions to all Firebase products (no granular, individual permissions).

Comment: You might want to read about Google Cloud IAM for limiting the scope of service accounts to particular products and product capabilities. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs And also Firebase IAM roles: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles

Comment: Thanks for the links. To be clear by going through the Firebase console, the service account key grants access to all Firebase products? If the key needs to be restricted I need to go through the Google Cloud console?

Comment: The documentation should be clear about what you have to do in any case. Every product has its own way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't phrase my last question correctly. 
For future reference, by default owner and editor roles have "edit access to all Firebase and Google Cloud Platform resources". You can also grant access to specific Firebase products or to groups of Firebase products.

Comment: There is very few articles about service account can anyone explain me in short what is for , and use cases of service account

Comment: Is it possible to deploy a firebase function selecting it's gcloud account? Something like $ firebase deploy --only functions --service-account=my-account@gcloud.com